# Correct way to add points and calculate distances in miles using postGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm brand new to PostGIS and want to create a column in my database for a new place that stores its latitude and longitude (a 2D point). Later I will want to be able to find the distances between these two points.

It seems I can accomplish what I want by running the following queries:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

CREATE TABLE places (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    location geometry NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO places (name, location)
VALUES ('The Place of Luke', ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-71.1043443253471, 42.3150676015829),4326)),
('The Place of Bob', ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-75.1043443253471, 43.3150676015829),4326));

SELECT ST_Distance(
        (SELECT location FROM places WHERE name = 'The Place of Luke'),
        (SELECT location FROM places WHERE name = 'The Place of Bob')
    );
```

I believe this is correctly returning the distance in latitude and longitude of `4.12310562561766`, but I have several questions about best practice.

1. Is `geometry` the correct type for what I am trying to accomplish? I tried changing `geometry` to `point`:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE places (
       id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
       name VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
       location point NOT NULL
   );

   INSERT INTO places (name, location)
   VALUES ('The Place of Luke', ST_MakePoint(-71.1043443253471, 42.3150676015829)),
   ('The Place of Bob', ST_MakePoint(-75.1043443253471, 43.3150676015829));

   SELECT ST_Distance(
       (SELECT location FROM places WHERE name = 'The Place of Luke'),
       (SELECT location FROM places WHERE name = 'The Place of Bob')
   );
   ```

   but I kept getting `ERROR:  column "location" is of type point but expression is of type geometry`. I understand that ST_MakePoint is probably trying to create something of type `geometry` and that is causing the error, but how do I create something of type point?
2. The [documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html) seems pretty insistent that I should be using `AddGeometryColumn()` instead of adding the column directly to my places table, but I don't understand why and if this will be a problem as my application grows. If all I need to do is find the distance between two places (on a 2D plane) for travel distance by land, will this be a problem for me?
3. How can I convert this result into miles (and possibly kilometers). Should I be running a different query all together? My understanding of longitude and latitude makes me think that this number being returned will not be a simple linear conversion to miles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, never use `point` if you're using PostGIS. Point is a native type. PostGIS is an extension to do just what you want. If everything is in 4326, you should look at the `geography` type and use it.
2. Never use `AddGeometryColumn()` unless you're using PostGIS 1.x. PostGIS 2.x supports type modifiers, and you can use `ALTER TABLE` instead.
3. To use get miles, simply return km and `* 0.621371192`

This is slightly weird, but functional.

```
SELECT ST_Distance(
    (SELECT location FROM places WHERE name = 'The Place of Luke'),
    (SELECT location FROM places WHERE name = 'The Place of Bob')
);
```

Typically you see this in a JOIN working over batches, but it works in correlated subqueries as you're intending too.

```
SELECT
  l1.location,
  l2.location,
  ST_Distance( l1.location, l2.location )
FROM location AS l1
JOIN location AS l2
  ON l2.location = 'The Place of Luke'
WHERE places = 'The Place of Bob';
```

Comment: also questions like this are better answered on gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using

- Use `geography(Point,4326`) as the data type for location
- Query as `ST_Distance(location1::geography, location2::geography)`

By casting to `geography` data type, the result is in `meters`, instead of degrees, which would be meaningless. Note that 4326 is the same system as WGS84 (what most GPS data is referencing)

See also this Q/A for more details:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76967/what-is-the-unit-used-in-st-distance

edit:

re: `AddGeometryColumn`  it is not required to use that function, it just a convenience- as far as I know.

edit:

An additional note, not something you asked about, but there is also spatial index type in postgis:

```
CREATE INDEX loc_idx ON places USING gist (location);
```